# header file missing error with ionic build command only

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

Right now we are trying to do build one application which is using braze plugin.

error is like below

```
/IDFADelegate.m:1:
/Users/jenkins_slave/workspace/MiTigo/app/dev/frontend-ios/platforms/ios/MiTigo/Plugins/cordova- 
plugin-appboy/IDFADelegate.h:2:9: fatal error: 'ABKIDFADelegate.h' file not found
#import "ABKIDFADelegate.h"
```

which results in below error

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/nirmalbhagwani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MiTigo- 
 afjftydkcjntqcarsrbihapxruva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MiTigo.build/Debug- 
 iphonesimulator/MiTigo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/IDFADelegate.o 
 /Users/nirmalbhagwani/Documents/GitHub/Millicom_MiTigo_Ionic/platforms/ios/MiTigo/Plugins/cordova- 
 plugin-appboy/IDFADelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

same build works quite fine when we run it through xcode but fails with command

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

any help here will be appreciated.